# How to add Map Legend, Scale Bar and Select tool to an ArcGIS Server Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-service, legend, scale

I have published a service from ArcMap to my Server Account but I can't figure out how to add the legend, scale bar and select tool to the service. According to the published service it was built using ArcGIS JavaScript API. Will I have to write some code in order to display what I want?

Answer (score 1):

you can write code using the [one of the arcgis Api's](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/)  code or use http://www.arcgis.com/ .
For arcgis.com: create a account and then open the map, select add layer from web, enter the url of your service. -> save and share

Comment: Hi Thank you for your repsonse. I have found a video whioch shows how to copy codes to use for services for Javascript. I'm struggling however to understand which directory to save the code in. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/videos/sample_using.htm